# Modifying a YUI RTE toolbar after it's been created

Tags: javascript, yui, rte

I am in a situation where I do not control the creation of one or many [YUI Rich Text Editors](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/); it is done in someone else's library.

For the purposes of this discussion:

- patching code-- monkey or otherwise-- is not an option.
- removing (`editor.destroy()`) the editor that's already there and adding my own is also not an option. The code that creates the editor does *Other Things* to it and refers to the reference etc-- I need to **modify the current editor**.

By creation I mean:

```
var myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor(control, {
  // toolbar config would go here if I controled this code
});

myEditor.render();
```

The problem is that I would like these editors to have a different toolbar configuration to what they have. To be precise, I would like to remove a bunch of buttons (The [default](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/toolbar_editor.html) is a bit bloated).

I managed to get the editor with the [`EditorInfo`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.EditorInfo.html) tool, but I couldn't really do anything with it. There is [apparently](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.SimpleEditor.html#property_toolbar) a variable on the Editor that allows you to get the [`Toolbar`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.Toolbar.html) instance but when I tried it all I got was `null`.

So, **is there a way to modify a YUI Rich Text Editor after `render()` has been called to remove toolbar buttons?**

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't see the code, it's a little hard to give an answer. But once you have access to the Editor instance, the toolbar property should give you full access to the addButton/detroyButton methods.

```
var editor = YAHOO.widget.EditorInfo._instances['editor_id'];
editor.toolbar.destroyButton('bold'); //This should destroy the bold button
```

That code should work. If editor.toolbar is null, then you may be accessing it before the toolbar is created. You can try this:

```
editor.on('toolbarLoaded', function() {
  this.toolbar.destroyButton('bold');
});
```

Again, it's a little tough to debug without seeing the code or having access (Firebug) to the page.

I don't use this site, so you may want to ask the question on the official [YUI mailing list](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/ydn-javascript/) so others can learn too ;)